# Deleting entity when a referenced entity is deleted

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity-framework-6

Using DDD, I have 4 aggregate roots where, using the appointment analogy, a clinic can have a number of patients, each patient can have a number of appointments, each appointment can have a number of prescriptions.

Now, to avoid creating a very big bloated Aggregate, Clinic in this case, I have created 4 separate aggregate roots.

```
public class Clinic
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public Guid ClinicId { get; private set; }

    public Patient(Guid clinicId)
    {
        ClinicId = clinicId;
    }
}


public class Appointment
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public Guid PatientId { get; private set; }

    public Appointment(Guid patientId)
    {
        PatientId = patientId;
    }
}
```

Now, the question is how should I manage the scenario where a patient is deleted, in which case all appointments referencing this patient should be deleted too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is where a domain expert is going to come in handy.  From a technical point of view it probably is going to depend on the architecture you decide on.

**100% consistency**

Here you could use an application service to first delete the patient and then all the appointments linked to that patient.

**Eventual consistency**

Using messaging you could publish `PatientDeletedEvent` that would be responded to by some endpoint that would delete the appointments.

**However**

You probably do not want to be deleting patients in the first place.  Even so, your questions about the appointments for, say, setting a patient `Inactive` may still results in you wanting to delete *future* appointments.

This is where you would need a domain expert to guide you in creating the correct model and behaviour.